# executing multiple commands in .bat with a lot of special parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Its as simple - I want to execute one command after another from top to bottom.

This might sound crazy but I want to use a lot parameters e.g.

```
PUSHD %~dp0

wkhtmltopdf.exe --no-stop-slow-scripts --debug-javascript --javascript-delay 15000 --images --print-media-type "http://ridiculous.lo/ng?url=with&strange=%parameters&including=every%20special%20character%25youCanImagine" filename.pdf

wget -m --recursive --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --no-parent http://ridiculous.lo/ng?url=with&strange=%parameters&including=every%20special%20character%25youCanImagine"

POPD %~dp0
```

Just that. Commands are running fine, when entered 'by hand' into cmd.exe.

What is the best way? Do I really need to replace the hell out of the parameters?

START and CMD require really annoying handling with strings etc.

Please make my day.

Update req. by comment

Some kind of real command:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --no-stop-slow-scripts --debug-javascript --javascript-delay 15000 --images --print-media-type "http://someServer:1337/php/rework/autogen.php?step=AggregationController&AggregationType=PG&PG_textBox=&PG%5B%5D=S2-1113F&ID_textBox=&AGG_textBox=&CHA_textBox=&RO_textBox=&TECH_textBox=&TO_textBox=&RR_textBox=&CRITIC__textBox=&LE_textBox=&MODULE__textBox=&preselect=x&view=default&HistoryFilter=%25SH32%25&latestWorkWeek=2013_WW08&view=cuNoAjax&pageBreakOverview=70" nameOfPDF.pdf
```

note, url works fine in browser - thanks so far to all

#### Answer found in comments by rojo:

Simply replace `%` with `%%` and nothing else! (tried so much more).

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Where you have `%20` and `%25` in the URL's you're building, be sure and use double percents to signify literal percent symbols so the batch script knows you don't want (argument 2)0 and (argument 2)5.

Comment: But that is not all I would need to replace. What about & ? And maybe /?  http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php Much Pain for such a little task :(

Comment: I think as long as the `&` and `>` and `|` and so forth are within the quotation marks, they'll be fine, although you might still need to escape carats `^`.

Comment: where should I do it exactly? inside the "" ? inside somthing cmd thingy?

Tried some combinations neither of them worked.

Comment: Can you add an example full URL to your question so we can test what works?  And are these URL's generated at the batch script's runtime, or are they static?

Comment: Done in original post. Thanks so far.

Comment: Ya, in the example you listed, the only thing that needs to be done is to change the percent symbols to double percents.  So instead of `%5B%5D` you need `%%5B%%5D`.  Everything else outputs the way it should, no escaping needed.  If changing the percents to double percents is impractical for you, then maybe you could URL decode the characters and use their literal values rather than encoded equivalents (for instance `[]` instead of `%%5B%%5D`).

Comment: @rojo some time has gone - but this made it! I would simply accept this as an answer if it would be possible.I totally would accept this as an answer, if it would be possible. But until then I will update my question to save others some time. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then.  Thanks for the karma!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you listed, the only thing that needs to be done is to change the percent symbols to double percents. So instead of `%5B%5D` you need `%%5B%%5D`. Everything else outputs the way it should, no escaping needed. If changing the percents to double percents is impractical for you, then maybe you could URL decode the characters and use their literal values rather than encoded equivalents (for instance `[]` instead of `%%5B%%5D`).

Answer (score 1):

Remember before you write your batch script that does all that crazy stuff to set your path. Browse to the path you want to get to, modify start in path, or just simply do a cd\ cd.. or whatever it takes to get to the path you need to be at.  Put a pause after the contents to debug and see what's going on (may go to quickly). Also use your echoes to see what the CMD window says.

Remember you can also do a cmd /c  to run commands. Also ensure that your batch file and session has proper administrative credentials. You may have to run in elevated user mode if required.

If you tell us what your OS is saying as well it'll be helpful for us to help you.

Comment: I am currently using WinXP - I am at work :/, I need to get this commands running from a one click file thats located on a network share simplyfying work for collegues (that could use win7)

Comment: UNC paths don't play well in Windows XP+. Is there anyway you can map the network drive and then have it run? Maybe upon run have it copy locally , then execute? NET USE is the batch commmand to map drives dynamically.

Comment: Don't get it personally, but this sounds like a way that should be gone. Isn't there a better one? :(